# How to use JSON in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, json, yii

I want to send/get a variable to/from controller action. My codes:

**view file**

```
....
<button id="radiyo">radio</button>
<script>
$("#radiyo").on("click", function(){
    var $radio = $('input[type=radio][name=siniflerin-siyahisi]:checked').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?=Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/ideyalar/sech/radio',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {radio: $radio},
//        datatype: "html",
        success:function(){

            alert($radio);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?=Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/ideyalar/sech/radio',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        datatype: "json",
        data: {change: $sql},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.change);
        }
    });
});
</script>
....
```

**controller action**

```
public function actionSech ($radio)
{
    $sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select ('m.maraq')
        ->from ('maraq m')
        ->where ('m.idsinif=:ids', [':ids'=>$radio])
        ->queryAll();
    $gonderilen = CJSON::encode(['change'=>$sql]);
}
```

I read articles from Yii offical site and other forums. But I couldn't understand how can I do it.

Please tell me, how can I send `$sql` variable to my **view file**?

Thanks.

Comment: Can u please give me more information on how the json output should look?

Comment: thanks for attention. As checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry.. I think I wasn't clear in my question. Normally what i do is, loop through the query results and format it the way i want. eg. 
$change = array();
foreach($sql as $s){
 $change[] = $s->maraq;
}
echo json_encode($change);

Comment: okay. If I correctly understand this codes should be write in **controller action** yes? And how can I receive the `SQL query` result in view file?

Comment: Yeah this code will replace the line "$gonderilen = CJSON::encode(['change'=>$sql]);" in your controller action.. Firstly why do make two ajax requests on clicking a checkbox?? Based on your answer to this question i can help u further

Comment: Oh thanks. 
With 1st ajax request I send the `selected radio button id` to the controller as `$radio`. With this variable I execute the `SQL query`. *This query retrieve the data which I want.* after this I want to refresh `multiselect checkbox group` with specific checkboxes. for more info you can visit  [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095235/sort-checkboxes-with-selecting-radios)

I think I can explain what I want to do. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62424/discussion-between-coni-and-balaji-viswanath).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure what you want. But, I want to pointing out some snippet.

In view file

```
<?php
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("header-info","
        var baseUrl = '".Yii::app()->baseUrl;."';  
    ",CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
?>

<button id="radiyo">radio</button>
<script>
    $("#radiyo").on("click", function(){
    var radioValue = $('input[type=radio][name=siniflerin-siyahisi]:checked').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl +'/ideyalar/sech',
        dataType:'json',
        type:'POST',        
        data:{radioValue:radioValue},
        async:false
        }).done(function(data){
         if(data['status'] == 'OK'){
             alert(data['returnValue']);
         }else if(data['status'] == 'ERROR'){
             alert("HERE WE GO ERROR");
         }
     });
   });
</script>
```

Your controller action;

```
public function actionSech()
{
   //In my point, I never call db layer in controller. Controller should be routing purpose

   If(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
      $radioValue = isset($_REQUEST['radioValue']) ? $_REQUEST['radioValue'] : "";
      $returnObj = array();
      if($radioValue !=""){
         $query = "SELECT `maraq` FROM maraq WHERE idsinif='$radionValue'";
         $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar();
         if($result != "" || $result != null){  //ensure result is correct or not
             $returnObj['returnValue'] = $result;
             $returnObj['status'] = 'OK'; 
         }else{
             $returnObj['status'] = 'ERROR'; 
         } 
      }else{   //if radiovalue is blank string
         $returnObj['status'] = 'ERROR';
      }
      echo json_encode($returnObj);
   }
}
```

Hope this help! Btw, JavaScript variable can't not initialize with **$**. Just only **var yourVar="";**